# SideMenu in Swift ignores UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent

Tags: ios, swift, uistatusbar, side-menu

I am using a third party library called SideMenu, which can be found [here](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu). It works like a charm, but in my app, I use a white status bar `UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent`. I set this up in the entire project: in the deployment info and programmatically:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

In `viewDidLoad()`, I also call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()`. It works on all ViewControllers, except when I use the SideMenu. When it appears, the text of the StatusBar becomes black and when I close it, it doesn't turn white again. It only becomes white when I go to another ViewController where the `preferredStatusBarStyle` is overridden.

Any ideas on how I can fix this? Do I need to call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` somewhere else? I have tried to look at the source code of SideMenu and tried to implement it in the transition function, but this was unsuccessful as well.

Note: I have set up my project with `.lightContent` in the deployment info, but still my ViewControllers show black status bar if I don't override the `preferredStatusBarStyle`. Maybe this can be the issue as well - it is by default not white but black, even though I set it to `.lightContent`?

EDIT: I also use these extensions to make the color of the StatusBar work using TabBarController and NavigationController. Issue could be in here as well:

```
extension UITabBarController {
    open override var childForStatusBarStyle: UIViewController? {
        return selectedViewController
    }
}

extension UINavigationController {
    open override var childForStatusBarStyle: UIViewController? {
        return visibleViewController
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried subclassing the side menu class, overriding that method, and using that subclass?